# vuetify says that This dependency was not found

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I got an error when building a vue-cli app with vuetify framework.

```
This dependency was not found:

* vuetify/es5/components/VCardTitle in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vuetify/es5/components/VCardTitle
```

When I try to install it it says:

```
error Received malformed response from registry for undefined. The registry may be down.
```

Any ideas what it could be?

package json: `"vuetify": "^1.1.12"`

Im using vuetify a-la-carte.
I have also added `VCardTitle` to the vuetify.js file in imports and components.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from `'vuetify'` as it is in Vue Official Documentation example (https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte).
Change it to `'vuetify/lib'`.

Example:

`import {
  Vuetify, // required
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar,
  transitions,
} from 'vuetify/lib';`